# Android listview item with multiple text creation dynamically?

Tags: android, android-listview

I Want to create mulitple `TextView` dynamically in `ListView` item. suppose i use `LinearLayout` it will create textview horizontal or vertically. I want multiple textview with the wraping. How can i create like that please share your valuable ideas,

Below screen images.

[image]

**Note :**
Each textview have the click action

Mike voted 8 , lara voted 9 like that individual text with wraping conetxt.

Comment: If you want wrapping, use a single multiline textview.

Comment: @GabeSechan i have click action with each textview

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem, whit textviews in linearLayout? But I think, what you really looking for is spannable string,in this case you can set the formats (colour, font size, style and what ever you want, and onClick actions for every word, and you need just one text view.

Comment: how you can show one textview with multiple click action? can you pls brief this? thanks

Comment: I have a custom view (merge xml) that contains a text view (originally it's a more complicated view).
My custom view class like this

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom view (merge xml) that contains a text view (originally it's a more complicated view).
My custom view class like this

public class Example extends LinearLayout {

protected Context context;

protected TextView titleView;

```
public Example(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) `enter code here`context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.bloghu_title_layout, this, true);
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    titleView = (TextView) getChildAt(0);
}

public void setBlogTitle(String blogTitle, final String blogUrl, String author, final String authorUrl) {
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

    spannableStringBuilder.append(blogTitle.toUpperCase());
    spannableStringBuilder.append(" / ");
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, blogTitle.length() + 2, 0);
    spannableStringBuilder.append(author);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.2f), spannableStringBuilder.length() - author.length(), spannableStringBuilder.length(), 0);

    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new NonUnderlineClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Log.d("span", blogUrl);
        }
    }, 0, blogTitle.length(), 0);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new NonUnderlineClickableSpan() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(context, authorUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, spannableStringBuilder.length() - author.length(), spannableStringBuilder.length(), 0);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.index_orange)), 0, blogTitle.length(), 0);
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black)),
            spannableStringBuilder.length() - author.length(), spannableStringBuilder.length(), 0);
    titleView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    titleView.setText(spannableStringBuilder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

}

The NonUnderlineClickableSpan() is an extended ClickAbleSpan(), it just because I don't want to underline the clickable text, end it has an empty onclick method that you have to override:
public class NonUnderlineClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{

```
@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
   ds.setColor(ds.linkColor);
   ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
}

@Override
public void onClick(View widget) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

As you can see in Example class you can set a new NonUnderlineClickableSpan, in its' onClick() method you can set what to happen, than you have to set the first and the last character of the clickable span, and a flag (this is the last parameter, in this case 0).

Whit ForegroundSpan you can set font color, whith relative size span you can set different text sizes, and there are a lot of span to style your text and make it interactive, but it is a very under-documented part of android.

I haven't found a good tutorial about this topic yet, so if somebody know one, pls let me know :).

Comment: This is the kind of tutorial you're interested in? http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177 or http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/ ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially for the second one!